# Why is this function crashing my program?

Tags: c#

I'm new in programming and this is my first project and I'm using C#. Basically I tryed to do a function that insert one more single quote in string that already have a single quote, but this is crashing my program and I don't know why.

The function:

```
private string CheckSingleQuote(string txt)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < txt.Length; i++)
        if (txt[i] == '\'')
            txt = txt.Insert(i, "'");
    return txt;
}
```

When I click in a specific button, this function is called ten times to set the value of the strings.

Comment: If you find a quote you add a new one. Then you go to the next character and find the quote you just added. So you add a new one. Then you go to the next character and find the quote you just added. So you add a new one. etc etc

Comment: What you want to do instead is call `String.Replace` once. Or if you really want to persist with this strange approach, iterate through the string in reverse.

Comment: Can I ask _why_ you are using this function? You aren't using it to build SQL strings are you?

Comment: @mjwills Oh yes, I didn't notice that. Thanks! And yes, I'm using this to call INSERT/UPDATE SQL Querys, unfortunately with my low knowledge this was the only way I thought for querys in varchar.

Comment: OK then the duplicate is wrong. The correct duplicate is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection . **You need to stop calling that function you are using to build SQL right now**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `String.Replace("'", "''")` or if you want to use the for:

```
private string CheckSingleQuote(string txt)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < txt.Length; i++)
        if (txt[i] == '\'')
            txt = txt.Insert(i++, "'");
    return txt;
}
```

As mjwills said in the comment the i++ is to skip the ' character that you just inserted.

Comment: @Pedro do not do this if you are creating a SQL string, it will open your code to [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection). You need to [use parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection).

Comment: @DourHighArch I didn't know why he needed it. He wrote that comment after my answer. I just answered his question.